# Facebook feed story not posting when user input's nothing

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

The title pretty much says it all. A few days ago the FB.Feed was working normally. The user could hit the share button and simply post the pre made feed story to his timeline. Now there has to be some sort of user input involved in order for the story to get posted. Even if its just a white space. Has facebook changed something or what ?

here is the feed method :

```
 if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
     {
         int shareScore = m_score.globalScore;
         string shareMsg1 = "SAmple msg";
          string shareMsg2 = "Sample msg2";
         if (gameOverFlag)
         {
             shareScore = m_score.scoreForPost;
             shareMsg1 = "game overmsg1";
             shareMsg2 = "gameover msg2 ";
         }
         FB.Feed(
                link: "test.com",
                linkName: shareMsg1 + (DataHolder.holder.levelIndex + 1).ToString() + " FuBar",
                linkDescription: "Some text",
                linkCaption: shareMsg2 + shareScore + " and " + score.ToString() + " Stars",
                picture: "test.com/test.jpg",
                callback: LogCallback
            );
     }
     else 
     {
         FB.Login("public_profile,user_friends,email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
     }
```

I replaced the proper links with the fictional test.com in the given example.

Comment: prefilling the message is not allowed, it must be 100% user generated. did you go through the review process with the publish_actions permission already?

Comment: @luschn  
I'm not prefiling the message. The only data I'm prefiling is the link description and caption and so on. The problem is that if the user leaves the message empty the whole story does not get posted.